# Does testosterone level cause more sexual dream content?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, experimental-psychology, dreams, sexuality

I have long been interested in dreaming, including how dream content can shed some light on brain chemistry.

I did a search on the subject of testosterone levels altering dream content and see some anecdotal evidence from bodybuilding forums and [androgel users](http://www.drugs.com/answers/testosterone-androgel-side-effects-930681.html).

These people report wet dreams, while others report increased sexual content in dreams.

**Do elevated levels of testosterone cause more explicit sexual dream content?**